# Проект C++. При создании проекта с библиотекой SFML не может создаться .exe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml, exe

Я писал простую программу, которая может отображать картинку в окне, но при компиляции вылезает ошибка с содержанием: Не удаётся найти Progect1.exe. Хотя и показывается, что ошибок не имеется. Visual Studio 2022 года, но библиотека SFML 2017(максимальная). Код с ошибкой прилагается и помогите пожалуйста.

[image: Ошибка]

```
#include <SFML/Graphiss.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(Videmode(200, 200), "3D Test!");

    Circle Shape MyCircle(100.f);
    MyCircle.setFillicolor(Color::Green);
Wall:
    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("Wall.png");

    Sprite s;
    s.setTexture* (t)
        s.setPosition(20, 200);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        event event;
        while (window.pollevent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        return 0;
`
```

Comment: Замените картинку на текст кода, чтобы желающие могли его скопировать и попробовать у себя. Для редактирования вопроса под ним есть кнопка ```Править```

Comment: Приведите лог сборки (текстом). Картинка говорит о том, что программа не собрана. Либо вы забыли скопировать зависимости (.dll sfml) в папку с exe.

Comment: Я не знаю, как сделать этот лог. Перетыкал всё во вкладке "Сборка". Ничего не изменилось. Даже скопировал все .dll. Ничего.    Сборка начата…
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 1, пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: Запустите пересборку тогда. А файл .exe создался?

Comment: Нет. Я не знаю почему.

Comment: может он создался в другом каталоге?

Comment: Всё в одном каталоге.

Comment: я это к тому, что студия любит разложить по папкам по особому. И возможно бинарник лежит в немного "неожиданном" для Вас месте.

Comment: Я поискал по всему компьютеру и нашёлся только Project1.exe.recipe

Comment: Ну тогда значит все-таки сделайте пересборку и приводите лог. Там пишется, какой exe где создался.

Comment: кстати, есть ещё один чудный способ. Особо одаренные антивирусы, увидя новый exe, удаляют его как подозрительный. Ну мало чего. И поведение будет очень и очень похоже на описанное.

Comment: У меня Avast. И он бы показывал, что он удаляет exe-шник.